# Post permalink structure not found when adding a custom prefix

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm trying to setting the post permalink and category base like that:

Post URL: site.com/insights/%category%/%postname%/

Category Base: insights

The attachment here: tinyurl.com/y3jlqucq

But the post is return 404 - page not found. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In "Custom Structure" remove /insights/, it's on "Category base". Maybe it help.